# TypeError: object 'TK' has no len() keeps occurring

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When using tkinter I keep getting this error returning. It only occurs in this example of code, and seems to originate from the.pack() lines.

```
Callback :
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "c:\Users\celia\Desktop\ZackAi\zackaitkinter.py", line 16, in <module> 
    myPad.pack(root) 
  File "C:\Users\celia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2398, in pack_configure 
    + self._options(cnf, kw)) 
  File "C:\Users\celia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1473, in _options 
    cnf = _cnfmerge(cnf) 
  File "C:\Users\celia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 109, in _cnfmerge 
    for c in _flatten(cnfs): 
TypeError: object of type 'Tk' has no len()
```

Code :

```py
import random 
 
from tkinter import * 
 
 
while True : 
    root = Tk()  
     
    Greeting ="Dydh da !" 
    choicelist = "language practise(A), positive message (B) or a idea for thought (C)"  
    thing = ["You are doing well", "You look cute", "Keep smiling"] 
 
    myPad= Label(root, text = Greeting) 
    myPad2 = Label(root, text ="please type Yes to start") 
    
    myPad.pack(root) 
    myPad2.pack(root) 
 
    e = Entry(root, borderwidth= 70) 
    e.pack() 
 
    varrr= e.get() 
     
    if varrr == "Yes" or "yes": 
        labelthree = Label(root, "choose a task") 
        labelfour = Label(root, "language, happy message and ideas for thoughts") 
        labelthree.pack(root) 
        labelfour.pack(root) 
 
        e2 = Entry(root,borderwidth =50) 
        e.pack() 
    else: 
        labelstop =Label(root, text= "No problem") 
     
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It should be `.pack()` not `.pack(root)`.

Comment: also why do you have it in a loop? that is not how event-driven programming (which `tkinter` consists of) in this sense exactly works, this is how you would handle command line programms, but here you need to make user be able to change their choice without closing the window

Answer (score 0):

When using `pack()`, you don't need to give the parent element. `pack()` automatically places the widget inside of its parent element, which you assign to it during initialization:

`label = Label(parent, option...)`

[Label Docs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_label.htm)
[pack() Docs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_pack.htm)

Also, why did you surround the entire application in a `while True:` loop? This is generally frowned upon, and if you can describe what you are trying to do, I can recommend a different method to achieve what you are trying to do.